# Solving T-shaped maze (probability learning): differences between rats and humans

Tags: reference-request, learning, performance

From Jonah Lehrer's book "How We Decide", he mentions the experiments with rats and Yale undergraduates.

I found the paper that (presumably) matches the experiment of rats.

> Brunswik, E. (1939). Probability as a determiner of rat behavior. Journal of Experimental 
>   Psychology, 25, 175–197. [Reprinted in Hammond, K. R., & Stewart, T. R., 2001]

But the results seem to be somewhat different from what he described.

Could anyone tell me where I can find the paper about Yale graduates performing the maze task?

Here's the excerpt from the book,

> "Look, for example, at this elegant little experiment:
>   A rat was put in a T-shaped maze with a few morsels of food
>   placed on either the far right or the far left side of the enclosure.
>   The placement of the food was random, but the dice were rigged:
>   over the long run, the food was placed on the left side 60 percent
>   of the time. How did the rat respond? It quickly realized that the
>   left side was more rewarding. As a result, it always went to the
>   left of the maze, which resulted in a 60 percent success rate. The
>   rat didn't strive for perfection. It didn't search for a unified theory
>   of the T-shaped maze. It just accepted the inherent uncertainty
>   of the reward and learned to settle for the option that usually
>   gave the best outcome.
>   The experiment was repeated with Yale undergraduates. Unlike
>   the rat, the students, with their elaborate networks of dopamine
>   neurons, stubbornly searched for the elusive pattern that
>   determined the placement of the reward. They made predictions
>   and then tried to learn from their prediction errors. The problem
>   was that there was nothing to predict; the apparent randomness
>   was real. Because the students refused to settle for a 60 percent
>   success rate, they ended up with a 52 percent success rate. Although
>   most of the students were convinced that they were making
>   progress toward identifying the underlying algorithm, they
>   were, in actuality, outsmarted by a rat."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find this in a scientific paper, and it is not clear from the sources I did locate that this work was ever actually published. However, I found other sources that reference this work and several similar studies comparing humans to rats.

The study you mention is also referenced briefly in Tetlock's (2005) book on political judgment; a discussion of Tetlock's interpretation of the results can be seen on University of Pennsylvania's Language Log (2005). That blog post also indicates the experiments are discussed to some extent in a textbook by Gallistel (1993); finding that book may provide more information.

A paper by Spragg (1934) describes exploring anticipatory responses in both rats and human (student) subjects. Overall and Brown (1959) examined decision making behavior in rats and humans (students) using a maze task.

- Gallistel, Charles R. (1993). *The organization of learning (Learning,
  development, and conceptual change).* A Bradford Book: 662 pages.
  ISBN-13: 978-0262570985
- Language Log. (December 11,2005). Rats beat Yalies? Doing better by
  getting less information? Retrieved from
  http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002700.html
- Overall, J. E., & Brown, W. L. (1959). A comparison of the
  decision-behavior of rats and of human subjects. *The American Journal
  of Psychology, 72*(2) 258-261.
- Spragg, S. S. (1934). Anticipatory responses in the maze. *Journal of
  Comparative Psychology, 18*(1), 51-73.
- Tetlock, P. (2005). Expert political judgment: How good is it? How
  can we know?. Princeton University Press. ISBN-13: 978-0691128719